# Pymongo $size operator

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Is $size equivalent operator for query condition in pymongo?

like
{'a': {'$size': 3}}

for {a: [1,2,3]}

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand your question, but if you're asking if `db.foo.find({a: {$size: 3}})` would return the document `{a: [1, 2, 3]}`, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Hmm, i mean $size like query condition. I want to get documents, where size of array "a" == 3

Comment: Yes, you can use `$size` for that. You can't currently do range queries with `$size` -- that is, you cannot do `db.foo.find({a: {$size: {$gt: 3}}})`